# How to connect to an Intersys cache database in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, connection, intersystems-cache

I'm using PyCharm and I'm trying to connect to a database which is connected via the Intersys cache.
In many places online it is stated that I need to connect with the intersys.pythonbind2 module.

I don't have this module in PyCharm and cannot find where to download it.

I looked through many pages, but with no success. I know how to connect for example to Microsoft [SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server), but here it looks like the connection is totally different.

How can I do it?

Comment: https://cedocs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GBPY_intro#GBPY_intro_install

Comment: Thank you, this was one of the pages I saw on line, went through, followed to link to installation path - still didn't help me...

Comment: Re *"cache"*: Do you mean *"[Caché](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intersystems-cache/info)"*? The same for *"Intersys"* - do you mean *"[InterSystems](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intersystems-cache/info)"*?

Comment: *[Caché database system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterSystems_Cach%C3%A9)*

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I created the data source in [ODBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity) with the Intersys driver and then connected to it using pyodbc. Now I'm able to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry to bother you, but I'm currently attempting the same connection with a project I'm working on. I downloaded the intersystems driver, but was wondering if there was anything out of the ordinary when you put together your pyodbc connection string? From what I've seen, you need only add the hostname, port, and that's about it. Is this correct? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi! As far as I remember, there were different versions of InterSys Driver for ODBC and I had quite a challenge to find out what would actually work, for me it was version 2018.01.00.184 32 Bit version (although my machine is 64 Bit).

For the ODBC connection you need to specify Name, Host, Port, namespace, username and password.

And in the code I called this ODBC connection: conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN='ODBC_CONNECTION_NAME')

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the *[Try IRIS](https://www.intersystems.com/try)* site which gives you your online sandbox with IRIS (the next version of Caché) with examples of a connection from Python to InterSystems IRIS.

Answer (score 0):

I used jaydebeapi and dbutils for connection pool

```
   self.pool = PooledDB(
        creator= jaydebeapi,
        maxconnections=pool_size,
        mincached=pool_size,
        blocking=False,
        
        jclassname=self._DRIVER_PKG, #com.intersys.jdbc.CacheDriver
        url=self._CONNECTION_STR, #'jdbc:Cache://' + host+ ':' + str(port) + '/' + database
        driver_args= [user, password],
        jars = self._DRIVER_PATH, #esources/CacheDB.jar
    )
```